# Has the diophantine equation $xyz=n(x+y+z)$ for given $n\in \mathbb{N}$ only finitely many solutions $x,y,z\in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I don't know if this is considered a research question but I stumbled upon collecting formulae [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2378804/numbers-of-the-form-fracxyzxyz-second-question) for $n=\frac{xyz}{x+y+z}$ and the question is:

Does the diophantine equation $xyz=n(x+y+z)$ for given $n\in \mathbb{N}$ have only finitely many solutions $x,y,z\in \mathbb{N}$ or is there a $n$ such that it has infinitely many solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruling out the solution $(0,0,0)$, we have $xyz \neq 0$.
WLOG $x \geq y \geq z$, then $n(x+y+z) \leq 3n x$ and so we must have $yz \leq 3n$, in particular $\max(y,z) \leq 3n$. So there are finitely many possible $(y,z)$ and finally $x$ is determined by $(y,z)$.

Comment: Thanks! That was too easy, I should have thought of this myself!