# four variable ratio of product over sum, distinct variables

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2378804/numbers-of-the-form-fracxyzxyz-second-question) the form $xyz/(x+y+z)$ is discussed, and positive integer values of $x,y,z$ which make the form integral. My question relates to the four variable version $wxyz/(w+x+y+z).$ I wanted to find *distinct* positive integer values $w,x,y,z$ to produce a given positive integer result.

I found it was relatively easy to come up with formulas to do this, as long as the goal integer was at least $4.$ However I found no way to do it for the goal integers $1,2,3.$ So I'm asking for either examples or impossibility proofs for these cases.

In the case of goal $1$ there is $(1,1,2,4).$ But I could neither find nor disprove the existence of distinct positive integers $a,b,c,d$ for which $abcd=a+b+c+d.$ Any help on these questions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that this quotient cannot be $1$, assume WLOG that the numbers are in increasing order. Then $abcd < 4d \implies abc < 4$. But this has no solution in the positive integers for $a,b,c$ distinct (the smallest possible product of three distinct positive integers is $1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 =6$).

To show that it cannot be 2, the same argument as above leads us to $abc < 8$, which means the only possibility is $a=1, b=2, c=3$; this gives the equation $6d = 2(6 + d)$, which gives $d=3$, so there is no such solution in distinct positive integers for 2. However, replacing the coefficient in fact provides a solution $(1,2,3,6)$ for the quotient to equal 3; their product is $36$ and their sum is $12$.

Comment: I think this takes care of the goal being $1.$ Upvote for now, maybe accept later if goasls $2,3$ can be done in a similar way.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific as to what you mean by goals 2 and 3?

Comment: Oh, I think I get what you mean. For 3 we have $(1,2,3,6)$ works.

Comment: Yes, $(1,2,3,6)$ gives $3.$ (nice, will accept it now-- still wonder about goal $2,$ i.e. $wxyz=2(w+x+y+z).$

Comment: Does that help clear things up?

Comment: Yes, now all three cases, goals $1,2,3$ which I asked about, are finished.